# Creating heads of accounts and list sub headings in particular head in PHP

Tags: if-statement

I have an expenses section in my project. If I enter item like movie,shopping,lunch or dinner that should go automatically into entertaiment category and in my table, category should appear as Indirect Expenses(Entertainment) (because entertainment is a sub-category in indirect expenses).

[image]

```
if($txt="movie" || $txt="shopping" || $txt="Lunch" || $txt="dinner"){
           $category="Indirect Expenses(Entertainment)";
}
else if($txt="bus" || $txt="train" || $txt="flight" || $txt="auto"){
         $category="Indirect Expenses(Transport)"
}
else if($txt="book" || $txt="pen" || $txt="pencil" || $txt="newspaper"){
         $category="Indirect Expenses(stationary)"
}
else{
       $category="other";
 }
```

If I type movie,it will select Indirect expenses(Entertainment), but if I type "movie ticket", it is going to other category. How can I write the condition that it should take entertainment instead of other category and instead of Or condition can I gave them in an array like if($txt="['book','pen','pencil']")?

Comment: Could you provide us with a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example? Currently it sounds like you need someone to script it for you ;-) See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info

Comment: _"Can I do that? Is it possible to do?"_ - Most definitely. Most things are possible to do. First you need to make some attempts. If you then run into something _specific_, you need to show us what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Minor formatting and typo fixes;  I also removed "thanks" as according to SO guidelines that should not be included (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293655/thanks-in-advance-automatically-hint-user).